# InsertionSort on LinkedList data structure

Tags: java, c#, list, linked-list, insertion-sort

I have a List.cs file with this code:

```
class MyDataList : DataList
{
    class MyLinkedListNode
    {
        public MyLinkedListNode nextNode { get; set; }
        public double data { get; set; }
        public MyLinkedListNode(double data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
    MyLinkedListNode headNode;
    MyLinkedListNode prevNode;
    MyLinkedListNode currentNode;
    public MyDataList(int n, int seed)
    {
        length = n;
        Random rand = new Random(seed);
        headNode = new MyLinkedListNode(rand.NextDouble());
        currentNode = headNode;
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            prevNode = currentNode;
            currentNode.nextNode = new MyLinkedListNode(rand.NextDouble());
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        }
        currentNode.nextNode = null;
    }
    public override double Head()
    {
        currentNode = headNode;
        prevNode = null;
        return currentNode.data;
    }
    public override double Next()
    {
        prevNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        return currentNode.data;
    }
    public override void Swap(double a, double b)
    {
        prevNode.data = a;
        currentNode.data = b;
    }
}
```

And a Program.cs with this code

```
 class Insertion_Sort
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int seed = (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF;

        Test_Array_List(seed);

    }
    public static void InsertionSort(DataList items)
    {


    }

    public static void Test_Array_List(int seed)
    {
        int n = 12;
        MyDataList mylist = new MyDataList(n, seed);
        Console.WriteLine("\n LIST \n");
        mylist.Print(n);
        InsertionSort(mylist);
        mylist.Print(n);

    }
}
abstract class DataList
{
    protected int length;
    public int Length { get { return length; } }
    public abstract double Head();
    public abstract double Next();
    public abstract void Swap(double a, double b);
    public void Print(int n)
    {
        Console.Write(" {0:F5} ", Head());
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            Console.Write(" {0:F5} ", Next());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}
```

Could someone help me with the InsertionSort here? I'm having trouble getting the code to work even though there are plenty of examples online I can't get it to work on my case.

Comment: How have you tried to implement InsertionSort so far?  With what you've tried, what didn't work?

Comment: I've tried to recreate this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59968/performing-insertion-sort-in-c but i'm having trouble recreating everything without indexes and only using "nexts"

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the question to give you tid-bits about how to use insertion sort on linked list. Hopefully you would be able to learn and apply this in your code.

Basically insertion sort is like you sort cards in your hand. You pick one element scan it from right-left until you find a spot where your current card would fit-in. Idea is all cards in your hand are sorted while remaining cards lying are unsorted.

Using the same theory on link list, you start from head, pick up the first node, and create a sorted list. At the end, your input list should be null and sorted list would the list with all elements sorted.

Here is a pseudo code :

```
struct node* sort_link_list(struct node* plist) {

    /* empty list or only one element in a list */

    if(plist == null or plist->next == null) {
        return plist;
    }
    /* Head of sorted list, initially sorted list in null */

    struct node * head = null; 

    /* Scan each element of the input list */
    while(plist != null) {
        /* temp is the current node to be placed in sorted list */
        struct node* temp  = plist;
        /* input list is one short */
        plist = plist->next;

       /* if sorted list is empty or current node is to be placed in front */

        if(head == null or temp->val < head->val ) {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }else {
            /* scan the sorted list and place temp in the appropriate location */
            struct node *p = head;
            while(p != null) {
                /* position found or you reached end of the sorted list*/ 
                if(p->next == null or temp->val < p->val) {
                    temp->next = p->next;
                    p->next = temp;
                    break;    
                }
                p = p->next;
            }    
        }                
    }
    return head;
}
```